# ComboBox in a tableview cell in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to a add a `Combo Box` to my `Table View`:

Basically I have a class called TableViewTest that stores a name and a description, I can display theses names and descriptions in a `Table View` no bother, but what I want to do is add a third column with each cell having a `Combo Box` so that the user can select one from a number of options for each person.

So far I have created an `ObservableList` of type `String` with some values and added them to a `ComboBox` object. Does anyone know a way for me to add this `Combo Box` to the table?

Also bear in mind this code is pretty rough and I'm just trying to get something working and I'll be refactoring the code at a later date.

```
ObservableList<TableViewTest> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){

        // random String values
        products.add(new TableViewTest(b[i], a[i]));
    }

ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                "1",
                                "2",
                                "3"
                                );
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(options);

TableColumn<TableViewTest, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<> ("Name");
nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewTest, String>("name"));

                //price Column
                //Stock Column
TableColumn<TableViewTest, String> StockColumn = new TableColumn<> ("Stock");
StockColumn.setMinWidth(150);
StockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableViewTest, String>("description"));


TableColumn<Object,ComboBox> PriceColumn;
PriceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Source");
PriceColumn.setMinWidth(150);
   //PriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>
   //(options));

   //PriceColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new 
   //DefaultStringConverter(), options));


   //PriceColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn( 
   //comboBox));

TableView<TableViewTest> table = new TableView<>();

table.setItems(products);
table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, StockColumn, PriceColumn);
```

Comment: Your table column type should be the type of the data that is displayed in that column, not the type of the control that is used to display it. I.e. you need `TableColumn<..., String> priceColumn` (and I think it should be `TableColumn<TableViewTest, String> priceColumn`). Then you should be able to use a `ComboBoxTableCell`.

Comment: I really wish there were some FXML examples of this. Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

James_D's answer works well, but requires the user to click on the item to see the `ComboBox`. If you want to have `ComboBox`es in a column, that are always shown, you have to use a custom `cellFactory`:

#### Example:

```
public class TableViewTest {

    ...

    private final StringProperty option = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getOption() {
        return option.get();
    }

    public void setOption(String value) {
        option.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty optionProperty() {
        return option;
    }
    
}
```

```
    TableColumn<TableViewTest, StringProperty> column = new TableColumn<>("option");
    column.setCellValueFactory(i -> {
        final StringProperty value = i.getValue().optionProperty();
        // binding to constant value
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> value);
    });
    
    column.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<TableViewTest, StringProperty> c = new TableCell<>();
        final ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        c.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue != null) {
                comboBox.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue);
            }
            if (newValue != null) {
                comboBox.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue);
            }
        });
        c.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(c.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(comboBox));
        return c;
    });
```

Comment: By why wrap an observable in an observable like this? Surely you can implement an "always on" combo box without that level of indirection?

Comment: @James_D: Making this work with edit events would be more complicated. The other option would be to access the row value instead of the cell value, which I don't like, since IMHO the cellValueFactory should decide on the part of the item being displayed and the cellFactory should decide on the visual representation of that value.

Comment: Agree on the latter... but you can handle edits with just a couple of listeners, I think.

Answer (score 9):

The types for your table column are always the type of the item in each row (i.e. the same as the type you use for the table view) for the first type parameter, and the type of the (current) value for each cell in the column for the second parameter. So if your table view has type `TableViewTest`, and your combo box is selecting `String`s, you should have:

```
TableColumn<TableViewTest, String> priceColumn ;
```

The cell value factory should still map to a property in the `TableViewTest` class, i.e. assuming you have:

```
public class TableViewTest {

    // ...

    public StringProperty priceProperty() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

then you can do:

```
priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
```

or (much better):

```
priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());
```

Then you can just do:

```
priceColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(options));
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithComboBoxExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Contact> contactTable = new TableView<>();
        contactTable.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Contact, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        contactTable.getColumns().add(nameCol);


        TableColumn<Contact, String> categoryCol = new TableColumn<>("Category");
        categoryCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().categoryProperty());

        categoryCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("Friends", "Family", "Work Contacts"));

        contactTable.getColumns().add(categoryCol);

        contactTable.getItems().addAll(
            new Contact("Bill Gates", "Work Contacts"),
            new Contact("Barack Obama", "Friends"),
            new Contact("Tim Cook", "Work Contacts")
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(contactTable), 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Contact {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty category = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Contact(String name, String category) {
            setName(name);
            setCategory(category);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final StringProperty categoryProperty() {
            return this.category;
        }


        public final String getCategory() {
            return this.categoryProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setCategory(final String category) {
            this.categoryProperty().set(category);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently trying your code, but ran into problems since i need to have this working for java 7 so i cant use lamdas expressions, I think i found a way around not being able to use a lamda expression but i have now got another error on the `setcellFactory` method call.  


Incompatible types: Callback<TableColumn<Object,String>,TableCell<Object,String> cannot be converted to Callback<TableColumn<TableViewTest,String>

Comment: Java 7 is no longer publicly supported. We are (quite considerably) closer to the release date of Java 9 than the release date of Java 8 at the time of writing. There is really no reason at all to still be using a legacy version if you are writing a desktop application. For the error: you should not have `TableColumn<Object, String>` or `TableCell<Object, String>` anywhere in your code if you are using a `TableView<TableViewTest>`.

Comment: Ya your right, downloaded java 8 there and it works perfect. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to do basically the same thing, display a dynamic combo box in a column of a TableView. I'm sure these other solutions are flexible, but they seem needlessly advanced.

The simplest solution that I found, was to add a ComboBox property to my item class (in your case `TableViewTest`), create a public getter for it and treat it just like a standard `SimpleXProperty`. To then display it, simple set the cell value factory of the combo box column to a `PropertyValueFactory` and input the name of your getter.

The following code is in groovy, as it is the language I have implemented my project in, but should be nearly identical for Java:

Note that `ComboBoxItem` can be any class that you want to list in your combo box.

**In my custom table class which extends `TableView`:**

```
class CustomTable extends TableView<CustomTableItem> {

    CustomTable() {
        TableColumn columnA = new TableColumn("Column A")
        columnA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("propertyA"))

        TableColumn<CustomTableItem, ComboBoxItem> comboBoxColumn = new TableColumn<CustomTableItem, ComboBoxItem>("ComboBox Column")
        comboBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("comboBoxProperty"))

        getColumns().setAll(columnA, comboBoxColumn)
    }
}
```

**CustomTableItem**

```
class CustomTableItem {
    private SimpleStringProperty propertyA = new SimpleStringProperty()
    private ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox()

    CustomTableItem(String someValue, List<ComboBoxItem> items) {
        propertA.setValue(someValue)
        comboBox.getItems().setAll(items)
        comboBox.setConverter(new CustomStringConverter()) // Optional
    }

    String getPropertyA() {
        return propertyA.value
    }

    ComboBox getComboBoxProperty() {
        return comboBox
    }
}
```

**Finally, as a bonus, use a `StringConverter` to control how to display the objects in the combo box**

```
@CompileStatic
private static class CustomStringConverter extends StringConverter<ComboBoxItem> {

    @Override
    String toString(ComboBoxItem object) {
        return object?.toString()  // How the ComboBoxItem will be displayed in the combo box
    }

    @Override
    ComboBoxItem fromString(String string) {
        return null // Not used
    }
}
```