# Custom cell cactory for each cell JavaFX

Tags: java, design-patterns, javafx, cell, factory

I work with JavaFX since few weeks and after spending long time to deal with tableView & TreeTableView, i come to you to have a better understanding of Cell Factory.

My first question concern the global approach of CellFactory in JavaFX.

Normally a Factory is design to produce different objects with different behavior.
But, in JavaFX CellFactory seems to create the same type of Cell for an entire Column...

**What this approach respects the Factory Design Pattern ?**

If i want to change the behavior of the Cell depending on the content (value) of the Cell, i can't (as I have seen so far).

So my First question is (Drum roll...) :

**How can i create custom Cell Factory for each Cell in a Tablecolumn depending on the content of cell ?**

Answer (score 2):

> What this approach respects the Factory Design Pattern?

Yes it does. The whole point of the factory pattern is allowing the class using it (`TableView`) to create instances of classes adhering to a certain contract (`TableCell`) but hiding the concrete implementation from it.

The workflow shown in the diagram on this page: http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Just replace `Client` with `TableView` and `Product` with `TableCell`...

This allows to design reusable classes for `cellFactory` and `cellValueFactory` without having to change anything extending `TableView` / `TableColumn`.  (Just take a look at the [`javafx.scene.control.cell` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/package-summary.html); Most (or even all) cells in there have a static method to create a factory for it's type; These work independent from `TableView` items and could be used together e.g. with a `PropertyValueFactory`).

> How can I create custom Cell Factory for each Cell in a TableColumn depending on the content of cell?

You don't. You write a table cell that decides it's layout depending on the content passed by modifying the `text` and `graphic` properties ect. when the item changes (`item` property listener or `updateItem` method).

Example for cells displaying classes by showing a instance created using the default constructor:

```
column1.setCellFactory(v -> new TableCell<Class<? extends Node>, Class<? extends Node>>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Class<? extends Node> item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            try {
                setGraphic(item.getConstructor().newInstance());
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

This assumes you can decide the layout given the item value.

If you can't design clean code with this approach, consider combining it with the strategy pattern, i.e. let your items decide the layout of the `TableCell`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TableCellLayouter {
    void layoutCell(TableCell<?, ?> cell);
}
```

```
// the content could be more complex of course
TableView<TableCellLayouter> tv = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        cell -> {
            cell.setText(null);
            cell.setGraphic(new Rectangle(100, 100));
        },
        cell -> {
            cell.setGraphic(null);
            cell.setText("Hello world!");
        },
        cell -> {
            cell.setGraphic(new Circle(20));
            cell.setText("circle");
        }));

TableColumn<TableCellLayouter, TableCellLayouter> column1 = new TableColumn<>("a");
column1.setCellValueFactory(c -> Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> c.getValue()));

column1.setCellFactory(v -> new TableCell<TableCellLayouter, TableCellLayouter>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(TableCellLayouter item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            item.layoutCell(this);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: OK, If I understood correctly, change the factory is not the solution, but apply change to Cell on update() method is the only way.

In my case i display only text in cell so but the editing behavior must be différent depending on type of object in Cell
o i have to generate different textfield with different behavior when i edit different Cell, and i have to define it on startEdit() isn't it ?

Comment: @Doremus: Yes, cells can be reused for efficiency, but you decide in the factory, which cell class you use or if you modify the cell somehow. The `updateItem` method is not the only way to do this. Registering a listener to the cell's [`item` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#itemProperty) could also work and could be beneficial, if you need to undo changes depending on the item previously shown in the cell.

Comment: tks for your reply @fabian ! One last question, this listener on item property,  where do I define it ? In my custom cell factory ? in the class where i initialize my tableview ?

Comment: @Doremus: Inside the cell factory or your custom `TableCell` class. I've posted an example using a initializer in a anonymus subclass of `TableCell` here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35134148/2991525 . In that example I've subclassed `TableCell` to add a `ComboBox`, but if you don't need this, you can of course write something like this as cell factory: `v -> { TableCell c = new TableCell(); c.itemProperty().addListener(...); return c;  }`

Comment: @Doremus: I just noticed that I do not need to subclass `TableCell` in that linked answer and changed the code. You can still take a look at the previous version here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35134148/1 (But I think you can get the gist without doing that)

Comment: Tks @fabian for all your answer i will study your diffrent proposals !