# Refreshing a column of comboboxes in a table view, javafx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

so i have a table view with 3 columns and one of them is a column of comboboxes, the way i create the column of combobox is as so

```
    Source = new TableColumn<>("Configure Interface as..");
    Source.setCellValueFactory(i -> {
        final StringProperty value = i.getValue().optionProperty();
        // binding to constant value
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> value);
    });

    Source.setCellFactory(col -> {
        TableCell<TableViewTest, StringProperty> c = new TableCell<>();
        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        c.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue != null) {
                comboBox.valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldValue);
            }
            if (newValue != null) {
                comboBox.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(newValue);
            }
        });
        c.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(c.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(comboBox));
        return c;
    });
```

the column gets its values from the  getter method optionProperty() which resides within my TableViewTest class.

So the problem i'm having is I have another `combobox` (comboBoxA) that is above my `tableview` table in my gui, and when ever i change the value of comboBoxA i want to change the values of the comboboxes with the column.

I can do this by calling the following code within the method that is listening for the selection change of comboboxA

```
Source.setCellValueFactory(i -> {
    final StringProperty value = i.getValue().optionTwoProperty();
    // binding to constant value
    return Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> value);
});
```

but the values don't change unless is start scrolling down to near the bottom of the table. is there a way to force the comboboxes to change to the new values within the getter method optionTwoProperty() without me having to scroll down?.

**EDIT**

Okay so the line

```
      final StringProperty value = i.getValue().optionTwoProperty();
```

doesnt actaully get called until i start scrolling down.

Comment: Post the code changing the values. Since you use a modified version of my code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35134148/2991525 I tested this with `comboBoxA.valueProperty().addListener((a, b, c) -> {
            for (TableViewTest item : tableview.getItems()) {
                item.setOption(c);
            }
        });`, but wasn't able to reproduce the error.

Comment: the thing is i'm using a fxml file and my code is in the fxml controller file, so i dont have to set up a listener for the comboBoxA, instead just name the method i want to call when the selection is changed. the code im using to change the values is the `Source.setcellValueFactory` part

Comment: Can you show your declarations so we know the types of things? (And your model class might be helpful too.) Why is your cell value a property wrapped in a binding? Can't you just make it a `TableColumn<Whatever, String>` instead of `TableColumn<Whatever, StringProperty>`, which is what it appears to be?

Comment: And maybe step back a bit and explain what you're really trying to do here. Is the idea that you have a combo box at the top of the table that changes all the values (sort of a "set all" functionality)? It looks like you have just made this too complex in an attempt to get something to work.

Comment: so my tool will be getting info regarding each monitored session on a cisco switch and displaying it to the user, but will also allow a user to setup a span session using the tool. so the combbox (COMBOA)above the table view will have a list of all the sessions on the switch i.e session one, session two etcetera. so if i select session one from COMBOA then all the comboboxes within the tableview will have to change in regards to the information for session one ie. port one is input, port two is output.

Comment: if session two is selected then same should happen and the comboboxes within the table will display info regarding session two. but each combobox in the table view will have a number of options the user can choose from to set up a span port aswell. I'm trying to make this as easy as i can as i only started learning javafx 4 weeks ago so a lot of this is all new to me, but also at the same time i need this tool finished soon.

Comment: I know nothing about Cisco switches, so unless you can state that in a way that abstracts the information into a way I can understand it's going to be difficult to help. It sounds like you want to replace the table's items entirely when you choose something in the combo box, but maybe that's not correct. At the very least you should just need to update the properties in each item. Or just create a representative [MCVE]

Comment: the example you provided is what i need, but instead of updating all the comboboxes with the selected value of your combobox choice like in your code, i need to iterate through a arraylist of objects that i created and call a getter method for each object and update each combobox with the returned value. so object one returned a string "foo" and sets the first combobox to the string "foo", and the next object in the arraylist returns "bar" and sets that value of the second combobox to "bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with help from fabian, I think I understand that you want the combo box above the table to change the property in your model class that is represented in the cells in the table column.

One way to do this is to make the type of the combo box function that maps the model class to a property, and populate it with functions mapping to each of the properties you want.

Then you can represent the cell value factory for the table column with a binding that observes all the possible properties that could be represented, along with the selected value in the combo box, and returns the value computed by applying the function from the combo box to the model instance (and retrieving its wrapped value).

For the cell factory for the column, you can observe the selected value in the cell's combo box. When it changes, use the selected item in the combo box above the table to figure out which property to update.

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithSetAllComboBox extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> cellData.getValue().getName()));
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);

        TableColumn<Item, String> choiceCol = new TableColumn<>("Choice");

        ComboBox<Function<Item, StringProperty>> option = new ComboBox<>();

        option.getItems().add(Item::choiceProperty);
        option.getItems().add(Item::choice2Property);

        option.setCellFactory(lv -> createListCell());
        option.setButtonCell(createListCell());

        option.getSelectionModel().select(0);           


        ObservableList<String> choices = FXCollections.observableArrayList("First choice", "Second choice", "Third choice");

        choiceCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TableCell<Item, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(choices);
            cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node)null).otherwise(combo));
            combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (! cell.isEmpty() && newValue != null) {
                    Item item = table.getItems().get(cell.getIndex()) ;
                    StringProperty property = option.getValue().apply(item);
                    property.set(newValue);
                }
            });
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> combo.setValue(newItem));
            return cell ;
        });

        choiceCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        table.getColumns().add(choiceCol);

        choiceCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.createStringBinding( 
                () -> option.getValue().apply(cellData.getValue()).get(), 
                cellData.getValue().choiceProperty(), 
                cellData.getValue().choice2Property(),
                option.valueProperty()));

        choiceCol.setGraphic(option);

        choiceCol.setPrefWidth(200);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30 ; i++) table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i ,choices.get(0)));

        Button debug = new Button("Debug");
        debug.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().stream().
                map(item -> String.format("%s (%s, %s)", item.getName(), item.getChoice(), item.getChoice2())).
                forEach(System.out::println));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setMargin(debug, new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(debug);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ListCell<Function<Item, StringProperty>> createListCell() {
        return new ListCell<Function<Item, StringProperty>>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Function<Item, StringProperty> item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? null : item.apply(new Item("", "")).getName());
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final String name ;
        private final StringProperty choice ;

        private final StringProperty choice2 ;

        public Item(String name, String choice) {
            this.choice = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "Choice", choice);
            this.choice2 = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "Choice 2", "Second choice");
            this.name = name ;
        }

        public final StringProperty choiceProperty() {
            return this.choice;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getChoice() {
            return this.choiceProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setChoice(final java.lang.String choice) {
            this.choiceProperty().set(choice);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public final StringProperty choice2Property() {
            return this.choice2;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getChoice2() {
            return this.choice2Property().get();
        }

        public final void setChoice2(final java.lang.String choice2) {
            this.choice2Property().set(choice2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if I did understand the question, it's basically about changing the property displayed in the column (`i.getValue().optionTwoProperty()` <=> `i.getValue().optionProperty()`), which should probably be done by replacing the whole column... The `ComboBox` outside the `TableView` chooses the property used...(I guess) If I'm right this wouldn't work even if the cells would simply display text content instead of this `ComboBox` setup...

Comment: OK, that makes sense. It *should* be possible really just by replacing the `cellValueFactory`, but updating the `cellValueFactory` doesn't seem (though I need to test) to cause `updateItem` to be invoked on the cells (which seems like a bug). In theory you should be able to make the combo box a `ComboBox<Callback<CellDataFeatures<...>, TableCell<...>>>` and bind the `cellValueFactoryProperty` to its value, but an immediate test of that is not working for me. You could probably create a custom binding...

Comment: The custom binding would be problematic however, since here write access seems to be required.

Comment: You just need to pick an appropriate type for the combo box that picks the property: see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `TableView` not listening to modifications of the `cellValueFactory` property of the elements of it's columns. Therefore the `TableView` doesn't know it should redraw it's cells. In JavaFX 8u60 the `refresh()` method was added for this purpose (for some reason I can't find it in the online javadoc though), which allows you to change the code of your method changing the `cellValueFactory` like this:

```
Source.setCellValueFactory(i -> {
    final StringProperty value = i.getValue().optionTwoProperty();
    // binding to constant value
    return Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> value);
});
tableview.refresh();
```

In older versions you have to use the workaround of setting the column value to trigger a change in the list:

```
List<TableColumn<TableViewTest, ?>> columns = tableview.getColumns();
columns.set(columns.indexOf(Source), Source);
```

But this workaround could cease to work in future versions, since the list is not actually modified with this operation and triggering a list change event is not required by the contract of `ObservableList` (but replacing the `TableColumn` with a new instance (and copying the properties) should always work).

Comment: But all these workarounds should be unnecessary if things are set up correctly...

Comment: tableview.refresh(); helped a lot. Thanks @fabian :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say given the code snippets. Maybe you're not on the javaFX thread when doing the update? In that case use Platform.runLater(...), or share some minimal amout of code to reproduce the problem.